# Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup. Angular 5 Production build

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli, angular5

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup. at main.bundle.js:1
```

**Case:**

Error occurs on app start, after generating build using **`ng build --prod`**. However, the development builds, compiled using **`ng serve`** or **`ng build`**, are all working fine.

**What I tried:**

-Upgrading global and local `@angular/cli` to latest version i.e. `1.6.0`, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163932/3621001) answer.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "auth0-js": "^8.11.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/rx": "^4.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**Min code to reproduce error:**

[git/cli-reproapp](https://github.com/sataqi/cli-reproapp/)

Comment: Looks like a bug for angular cli https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8340

Comment: @Niladri seems so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the sample app you provided at [git/cli-reproapp](https://github.com/sataqi/cli-reproapp/) the error is occurring because of this line :-

> export const isInDevMode = isDevMode();

in file `cli-reproapp/src/app/app.constants.ts`. So as a workaround you can create a function instead of constant `isInDevMode` as is shown below. So that `isDevMode()` is called later (most importantly after `enableProdMode()` is called) when it is actually used in the code.

```
export function isInDevMode():boolean {
    return isDevMode();
}
```

Obviously after that you will also need to change the lines where "isInDevMode" constant is used with calls to the newly created "isInDevMode()" method. So in the sample app you will need to replace the below line in app.component.ts

```
this.title = isInDevMode ? 'App in dev mode works.' : 'App is prod mode works.'
```

with this one :-

```
this.title = isInDevMode() ? 'App in dev mode works.' : 'App is prod mode works.'
```

You can also see the working version of the sample app at the link  [git/cli-reproapp(working)](https://github.com/YyatharthY/cli-reproapp).

Comment: It helps. Thanks.

Comment: In my situation, I had to avoid calling isDevMode(); altogether to get it to work.

Comment: @java-addict301 Thanks, that was also the issue in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this error When I use the function `isDevMode()` in the `app.module` and built my app. I replaced it with `environment.production` and It solved my this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to remove isDevMode()in the app.module

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
          enabled: environment.production,
          // Register the ServiceWorker as soon as the application is stable
          // or after 30 seconds (whichever comes first).
          registrationStrategy: 'registerWhenStable:30000'
        }),
```

Comment: Please give a more detailed explanation on the codeblock you posted and how your solution is different from the original answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).